# How to Find People Who did Transaction Twice on The Same Day and Who did Transaction Consecutively in Less than 10 Minutes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have another table which looked like this:

```
+--------+--------+------------------------+-----------------+------------+
|orderid | userid | create_time            | payment_amount  | product    |
+--------+--------+------------------------+-----------------+------------+
|20001   | 1001   | 2018-04-02 5.26.21     |       48        |  key chain |   
|20002   | 1002   | 2018-04-02 7.44.13     |       25        |  pin       |     
|20003   | 1001   | 2018-04-02 8.34.48     |      320        |  tote bag  |    
|20004   | 1001   | 2018-04-02 8.37.23     |      180        |  mug       |   
|20005   | 1003   | 2018-04-02 9.32.08     |       21        |  key chain |   
|20006   | 1002   | 2018-04-02 9.33.10     |      200        |  tumblr    |   
|....... | ...    |      ...               |      ...        |     ...    |   
+--------+--------+------------------------+-----------------+------------+
```

I need to write two queries:

1. Find users who did transactions twice on the same day, what product were they bought and how much were they spend on the 1st transaction.
2. Find which users did transaction consecutively less than 10 minutes!

I am very appreciating for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give us your expected result from your sample data

Comment: Two questions seems to broad for a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1st query: Gives product were they bought and how much were they spend on the 1st and secund transactions

```
with cte as
(
  select userid, cast(create_time as date) as trx_Day 
  from tbl
  group by userid, cast(create_time as date) 
  having count(*) = 2
)
select a.userid, product, payment_amount, a.create_time            
from tbl a inner join cte b on a.userid = b.userid and 
cast(a.create_time as date) = b.trx_Day
order by a.create_time
```

2nd Query:

```
    select distinct userid 
    from tbl a where exists(select 1 from tbl b where a.userid  = b.userid  
and ROUND((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.create_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b.create_time)) / 60)< 10
)
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. But for the 1st query, I got an error: 'Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as trx_Day   having count(*) = 2 ), select a.userid, product, payment_amount, a' at line 5

Comment: Oh I just fixed it... Let me know

Comment: Unfortunetly still giving me error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;  the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select a.userid, product, paymentamount, a.create_time             from tbl a ' at line 8

Comment: I blame the late hour. JUst tested it myself... You should be ok now ebuzz168